# Apending to Linked List in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

The code compiles and runs but addToEnd method doesn't work, it seems right to me but I'm not sure where the mistake is, could someone guide me as to what or where the code needs to be fixed

Here is the code for my other class

```
 public class LinkedList {
 private Node head;


 /**
  * constructor
  * pre: none
  * post: A linked list with a null item has been created.
  */
 public LinkedList() {
  head = null;
 }

 /** 
  * Activity: finds size of the Linked List.
  * Pre-Condition: none
   * Post-Condition: The size of the list is returned
  */
 public int size() {
   int counter  = 0;
   Node current = head;

   while(current != null) {
    counter++;
    current = current.getNext();
  }
   return counter;   
}

  /** 
  * Adds a node to the end of the linked list.
  * pre: String parameter
  * post: The linked list has a new node at the end.
  */
 public void addAtEnd(String s) {
  Node current = head;
  Node newNode = new Node(s);
   if(head == null) {
     head = newNode;
     head.setNext(null);
   } 
   else {
     while(current.getNext() == null) {
       current.setNext(newNode);
       current = newNode;
   } 
 }
 }

 private class Node {
 private String data;
 private Node next;


  /**
   * constructor
   * pre: none
   * post: A node has been created.
   */
  public Node(String newData) {
   data = newData;
   next = null;
  }


  /**
   * The node pointed to by next is returned
   * pre: none
   * post: A node has been returned.
   */
  public Node getNext() {
   return(next);
  }


  /**
   * The node pointed to by next is changed to newNode
   * pre: none
   * post: next points to newNode.
   */
  public void setNext(Node newNode) {
   next = newNode;
  }


  /**
   * The node pointed to by next is returned
   * pre: none
   * post: A node has been returned.
   */
  public String getData() {
  return(data);
  }
 }
}
```

Here is my code for the main class, Blume and Dahl never get added to the list:

```
 public class LinkedListDemo {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

  list.addAtFront("Sachar");
  list.addAtFront("Osborne");
  list.addAtFront("Suess");
  System.out.println("List has " + list.size() + " items.");
  System.out.println(list);

  list.addAtEnd("Blume");
  list.addAtEnd("Dahl");
  System.out.println(list);
}
    }
```

Comment: `while(current.getNext() == null) {` should probably be `while(current.getNext() != null) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void addAtEnd(String s) {
  Node current = head;
  Node newNode = new Node(s);
   if(head == null) {
     head = newNode;
     head.setNext(null);
   } 
   else {// problem is here. You need to find the  node that has getNext()==null, 
         //so you need to loop all nodes where get next != null
     while(current.getNext() == null) { 
       current.setNext(newNode);
       current = newNode;
   } 
 }
```

Change to this

```
else{ 
    //iterate to the last node
    while(current.getNext() != null) { 
    current = current.getNext(); 
    } 
    //Append the new node to the end
    current.setNext(newNode);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (current.getNext() == null) {
    current.setNext(newNode);
    current = newNode;
}
```

This is just incorrect; because you're not keeping track of the tail of the list, you need to iterate over the entire list and then add `newNode` onto the end (which I believe you understand already).  To do this, just keep setting `current` to `current.getNext()` until `current.getNext()` is `null`, and then call `current.setNext(newNode);`

```
Node next;

while ((next = current.getNext()) != null) {
    current = next;
}

current.setNext(newNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addAtEnd(String s) {
    Node current = head;
    Node newNode = new Node(s);
    if(current == null) {
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        while(current.getNext() != null) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNext(newNode); 
    }
}
```

Comment: And it's not me who downvoted yours, I don't have points enough